# I'm not sure what is the purpose of "group by" here

Tags: sql, group-by

I'm struggling to understand what this query is doing:

```
SELECT branch_name, count(distinct customer_name)
FROM depositor, account
WHERE depositor.account_number = account.account_number
GROUP BY branch_name
```

What's the need of GROUP BY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a step away from SQL for a moment at look at the relational trainging language [Tutorial D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_%28data_language_specification%29).

Because the two relations (tables) are joined on the common attribute (column) name `account_number`, we can use a natural join:

```
depositor JOIN account
```

(Because the result is a relation, which by definition has only distinct tuples (rows), we don't need a `DISTINCT` keyword.)

Now we just need to aggregate using `SUMMARIZE..BY`:

```
SUMMARIZE (depositor JOIN account) 
   BY { branch_name } 
      ADD ( COUNT ( customer_name ) AS customer_tally )
```

Back in SQLland, the `GROUP BY branch_name` is doing the same as `SUMMARIZE..BY { branch_name }`. Because SQL has a very rigid structure, the `branch_name` column must be repeated in the `SELECT` clause.

Answer (score 6):

You must use `GROUP BY` in order to use an aggregate function like `COUNT` in this manner (using an aggregate function to aggregate data corresponding to one or more *values* within the table).

The query essentially selects distinct `branch_name`s using that column as the grouping column, then within the group it counts the distinct `customer_name`s.

You couldn't use `COUNT` to get the number of distinct `customer_name`s per `branch_name` without the `GROUP BY` clause (at least not with a simple query specification - you can use other means, joins, subqueries etc...).

Comment: +1 because your answer is really clear (more more than mine)!!

Comment: One can indeed use an aggregate function without `GROUP BY` e.g. `SELECT count(distinct customer_name) FROM depositor, account
WHERE depositor.account_number = account.account_number;`

Comment: "You couldn't use COUNT to get the number of distinct customer_names per branch_name without the GROUP BY clause." -- still wrong :) you should know there are always at least seven different ways to do *anything* in SQL ;) To do the count using no `GROUP BY` you can use a correlated sub query e.g. `SELECT DISTINCT a.branch_name, (SELECT count(DISTINCT customer_name) FROM depositor, account WHERE depositor.account_number = account.account_number AND a.branch_name = account.branch_name) FROM account a;`

Answer (score 3):

It's giving you the total distinct customers for each branch; `GROUP BY` is used for grouping `COUNT` function.
It could be written also as:

```
SELECT branch_name, count(distinct customer_name)
FROM depositor INNER JOIN account
ON depositor.account_number = account.account_number
GROUP BY branch_name
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to `COUNT` something (see `SELECT`-Part of the statement), you have to use `GROUP BY`  in order to tell the query what to aggregate. The `GROUP BY` statement is used in conjunction with the aggregate functions to group the result-set by one or more columns.

Neglecting it will lead to SQL errors in most RDBMS, or senseless results in others.

Useful link:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp